# Why does my remote control garage door opener not work when garage door is closed?

Tags: doors, garage

Why does my remote control garage door opener not work when garage door is closed.  It works fine when door is open but once the door is closed, it will not work.  Have reprogrammed same but still does not work.  Works if I am inside the garage or if door is open but once I am outside with the door closed, it will not open.  New batteries were also purchased and installed in remote.

Comment: This sounds like a product specific issue.  You should contact the manufacturer of the opener and/or remote.

Comment: It sounds as if the signal from the remote is having a hard time passing through the door.  Was this at one point working properly?

Comment: Yes, however, in the last year or two, it would do the same every once in a while but would eventually open.  Now it does not open at all.

Answer (score 3):

I find that stucco homes have this problem because of the metal mesh in the walls act like a faraday cage.
You may be able to extend the antenna to the exterior of the garage and it will work better.

Comment: I've seen the same problem with steel-sided pole sheds. Extended/external antennas were the only fix.

Comment: Not surprisingly they make garage door extenders for a number of different models (and some that are universal) because this is not an uncommon problem.  Although, it is still possible that some damage was done to the original antenna wire and it broke off, meaning that restoring it to original working order is all that's required.